# Dependancies problem when setting up detox

Tags: react-native, detox

I followed official documentation to set up Detox e2e testing framework but am stuck when trying to build with detox build.

Have any of you got this kind of errors?

Detox version 18.21.0

MinSDKVersion 18/21 - tried both

KotlinVersion 1.3.41/1.5.0/1.5.31 - tried all

> Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01.
> Required by:
> project :appCannot find a version of 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
> Constraint path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.1.0-rc01}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0-rc01
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5-cometchat.2' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'mobile:react-native-geolocation-service:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'mobile:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0' because of the following reasons: OneSignal override, ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'mobile:react-native-push-notification:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0' because of the following reasons: OneSignal override, ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'com.wix:detox:0.1.1' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'mobile:react-native-image-crop-picker:unspecified' --> 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2-native' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'mobile:app:unspecified' --> 'mobile:react-native-onesignal:unspecified' --> 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.5.1' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:[1.0.0, 1.3.99]'